# Bind r data.frames that contain column(s) of nested data.frames

Tags: r, tidyr, rbind, jsonlite

After importing multiple .json files using `jsonlite` I was looking for ways to bind the resulting data.frames which contained one or more columns which themselves were nested data.frames. 
I came across the following post https://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/data-frame-with-nested-data-frame-td3162660.html, which helped highlight the problem.

```
## Create nested data.frames
dat1 <- data.frame(x = 1)
dat1$y <- data.frame(y1 = "a", y2 = "A", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

dat2 <- data.frame(x = 2)
dat2$y <- data.frame(y1 = "b", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

None of these work

```
rbind(dat1, dat2)
dplyr::bind_rows(dat1, dat2)
data.table::rbindlist(list(dat1, dat2))
```

I've discovered a few workarounds which I'll post below in case they help others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be done without additional packages, too. The data frames need to be partly `unlist`ed within a `list` and then `merge`d using `Reduce`.

```
Reduce(function(...) merge(..., all=TRUE), Map(unlist, list(dat1, dat2), recursive=FALSE))
#   x y.y1 y.y2
# 1 1    a    A
# 2 2    b <NA>
```

This also works with more than two nested data frames.

```
dat3 <- data.frame(x=2, y=data.frame(y1="c", y2="C", z="CC", stringsAsFactors=FALSE))

Reduce(function(...) merge(..., all=TRUE), Map(unlist, list(dat1, dat2, dat3), recursive=FALSE))
#   x y.y1 y.y2  y.z
# 1 1    a    A <NA>
# 2 2    b <NA> <NA>
# 3 2    c    C   CC
```

#### Data

```
dat1 <- structure(list(x = 1, y = structure(list(y1 = "a", y2 = "A"), class = "data.frame", 
                                    row.names = c(NA, -1L))), row.names = c(NA, -1L), 
          class = "data.frame")

dat2 <- structure(list(x = 2, y = structure(list(y1 = "b"), class = "data.frame", 
                                    row.names = c(NA, -1L))), row.names = c(NA, -1L), 
          class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

Flatten the data first (for base `rbind` data.frames need to have identical column names)

```
dplyr::bind_rows(
  jsonlite::flatten(dat1),
  jsonlite::flatten(dat2)
)
```

Put the data.frames into a list before binding (all approaches now work)

```
dat1$y <- list(dat1$y)
dat2$y <- list(dat2$y)

rbind(dat1, dat2)
dplyr::bind_rows(dat1, dat2)
data.table::rbindlist(list(dat1, dat2))
```

Use the `tidyverse` to nest the data.frames

```
tib1 <- tidyr::nest(dat1, y = c(y))
tib2 <- tidyr::nest(dat2, y = c(y))
tib3 <- dplyr::bind_rows(tib1, tib2)
tidyr::unnest(tib3, c(y))
```